# Implement stricter requirements than in trait

Tags: rust

I have the following trait:

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo<U>(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U);
}
```

To implement it for a `BinaryHeap` I need to add an extra `Ord` constraint. Unfortunately, if I try to do so, I get a `[E0276]: impl has stricter requirements than trait` error.

```
impl<T: Ord> Foo<T> for BinaryHeap<T> {
    fn foo<U: Ord>(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U) {}
}
```

I can do it if I move the `U` type parameter into the trait

```
trait Foo<T, U> {
    fn foo(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U);
}

impl<T: Ord, U: Ord> Foo<T, U> for BinaryHeap<T> {
    fn foo(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U) {}
}
```

Which I don't like much since `U` is unrelated to the trait, but to the method only. Is there any other/better way to do this?

Comment: Could you add the code that forces you to restrict `U` to `Ord`?

Comment: Given that you can't construct a BinaryHeap with a T that isn't `Ord`, why do you need to add an extra `Ord` constraint?

Comment: @James the `Ord` constraint on `T` is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks @cafce25. Indeed the constraint on `T` is not a problem. The problem is `U`.

Answer (score 0):

You can require that `U` be Ord using the following implementation:

```rust
trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo<U: Ord>(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U);
}

impl<T> Foo<T> for BinaryHeap<T> {
    fn foo<U: Ord>(&self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U) {}
}
```